# Remove all attribute of a style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div><a id="link" style="position:fixed !important;
    bottom:0px !important;
    right:0px !important;
    color:#000000 !important;font:10pt Arial !important">press me</a>
</div>
```

In order to change that div block into

```
<div><a id="link" style="position:fixed !important;
    bottom:0px !important;
    left:100px !important;
    color:#000 !important;font:10pt Arial !important">press me</a>
</div>
```

(only the left property is different), I try this

1. Remove all attributes of style `($'#link').RemoveAttr('style');`
2. I would like to add the attributes of style back but there seems to be none of such AddAttr exists.

Comment: You shouldn't overuse the '!important' statement. It's a bad practice.

Comment: Instead of inline css, can u simply create two different css classes, and change them when needed?

Comment: the overuse of `!important` in this context points to bad css structure in general, or a lack of understanding of !important. I would look at trying to refactor some of the hierarchical styles in order to remove the `!importants` from inline styling

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use .attr('style', '') to remove, and .attr('style', '...'); to set the style back.

But it might be better to set the css styles to two different classes and use .addClass() and .removeClass() instead.

Answer (score 1):

the `.css()` method relates to inline styling as you have above rather than the `.attr()` method, so if the `left` property is all you wish to change, try:

```
$('#link').css({ 'right' :  'auto', 'left' : '100px' });
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a **bad practice** to use Inline styles..Also you need to avoid using **!important** as well..

Use classes instead of inline styles..

That looks lot cleaner

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <a id="link" class="link right" >press me</a>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
.link
{
    position:fixed !important;
    bottom:0px !important;
    color:#000000 !important;
    font:10pt Arial !important;
}
.right
{
    right:0px !important;
}

.left
{
    left:100px !important;
}
```

**Javascript**

Then you can just use `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` to get the things done..

```
$('#link').on('click', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('right').addClass('left');
});​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/3BTc2/)**

Answer (score 0):

you could do it this way one by one:

```
        $('#elementID').css('property','value');
```

or you could write some style properties on your css file like:

```
  .tobeadded{
   positon:relative;
   ...
    ...
  }
```

and then you could add this class to that element:

```
       $('#elementID').addClass('tobeadded');
```